# Получение данных из TableViewCell и запись в массив

Tags: objective-c, ios8

Привет всем! Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать будильник. 
Есть `TableViewCell` с фиксированным количеством ячеек (7 ячеек) - это дни недели, нужно получить данные из ячеек в зависимости от выбранных

вот код

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

вот картинка как все выглядит. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю, как получить данные из TableViewCell и записать их в массив для дальнейшей обработки.

Answer (score 1):

Подробностей вашей реализации я не знаю, но надеюсь помог.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSMutableArray* daysArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) { //Собственно какой тут индекс такой и день 

    AVDay* day = [AVDay alloc] init]; // День   

    [daysArray addObject:day];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В методе `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` используйте параметр `indexPath`. В свойстве `row` (`indexPath.row`) хранится индекс выделенной ячейки. По нему, можно понять какое значение вам нужно
2. Так как вы используете стандартные `UITableCellView` посмотрите в сторону свойств `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel`.